# CustomErrors logic when OwinStartup class throws an exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I've got a web app that I just inherited and it has a situation I can't figure out. It is setting up Redis in the class it has defined in the OwinStartup attribute. When Redis is unavailable for whatever reason, it throws an error (obviously). The customerrors redirect is sending the user to a URL that is handled by an MVC controller action. But because the error is in the OwinStartup, it gives me this error:

> An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally,
>   another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for
>   the first exception. The request has been terminated.

What I'm wondering is, is there any way to have a custom error page as a part of the MVC application like this and still have it work when the OwinStartup Configuration method causes an error?

Comment: Sounds like the owin auth is set globally and should in fact be set by controller

Comment: This is using `[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinStartup))]`. It's for MVC startup, not auth,